# Zero divisors in $\mathbb Q [T]/(T^4+T^2+1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I am asked to find all zero divisors in the quotient ring $\mathbb Q [T]/(T^4+T^2+1)$.

The most that I have come to is to take into account that if that set is a field and the polynomial is irreducible, then it has no zero divisors. But I have not not clear if this happens like this, since $\mathbb Q [T]$ is not a field. In any case, I have verified that this polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb Q$, so it is probably useful to solve the exercise.

What would be the best strategy to find what they are asking for?

Thank you all very much in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "the polynomial is NOT irreducible". So it must have zero divisors.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, $T^4 + T^2 + 1$ *is* reducible in $\mathbb Q[T]$, since
$$ T^4 + T^2 + 1 = (T^2 + T + 1)(T^2 - T + 1).$$

In the quotient ring, $\mathbb Q[T]/(T^4 + T^2 + 1)$, the elements $$a = [T^2 + T + 1]_{\text{mod }(T^4 + T^2 + 1)}, $$ $$b = [T^2 - T + 1]_{\text{mod }(T^4 + T^2 + 1)}$$ are zero divisors, since $$a \neq [0]_{\text{mod }(T^4 + T^2 + 1)}$$ and $$b \neq [0]_{\text{mod }(T^4 + T^2 + 1)}$$ but $$ab = [T^4 + T^2 + 1]_{\text{mod }(T^4 + T^2 + 1)} = [0]_{\text{mod }(T^4 + T^2 + 1)}.$$

Having given you this example, I'll let you think about how to construct other zero divisors in $\mathbb Q[T]/(T^4 + T^2 + 1)$. Think about how you can construct two polynomials that are not divisible by $T^4 + T^2 + 1$, but whose product is divisible by $T^4 + T^2 + 1$.

---

Incidentally, suppose the question was different. Suppose we were considering $\mathbb Q[T]/(T^2 + T + 1)$.

$T^2 + T + 1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Q[T]$, so the principal ideal $(T^2 + T + 1) \subset \mathbb Q[T]$ is a maximal ideal. Therefore, the quotient ring $\mathbb Q[T] / (T^2 + T + 1)$ is a field. Being a field, $\mathbb Q[T] / (T^2 + T + 1)$ has no zero divisors.

I'm mentioning this to show you that the line of logic that you were pursuing does work for rings of the form $\mathbb Q[T] / (f)$ where the polynomial $f$ is irreducible.

To recap, I've used three different facts:

- If $f \in k[T]$ is irreducible, then $(f) \subset k[T]$ is a maximal ideal.
- If $R$ is a commutative ring with unity and $M$ is a maximal ideal, then $R/M$ is a field.
- In any field, there are no zero divisors.

Comment: You're right. The polynomial is reducible into two polys of degree 2 with rational coefficients. Then, once we know them, say p(T) and q(T), I think the whole set of zero divisors would be {p(T)r(T), r(T) in Q[T]} and {q(T)s(T), s(T) in Q[T]}. Am I right?

Comment: @electr0n I'll give you some more examples:

Comment: - $[(T^2 + T + 1)(149T^16 - 59T^5 + \tfrac 1 9 T^2 + 4)]$ and $[(T^2 - T + 1)(888T^11 + 4 T^3 - T)]$ is a pair of zero divisors. Neither of these elements is equal to $[0]$, yet their product is equal to $[0]$.

Comment: - $[(T^2 + T + 1)(2T^4 - T^3 + \tfrac 3 8 T^2 + T + \tfrac 9 5)]$ and $[(T^2 - T + 1)(16T - \tfrac 4 9)]$ is a pair of zero divisors. Neither of these elements is equal to $[0]$, yet their product is equal to $[0]$.

Comment: Now consider $[(T^2 + T + 1)p(T)]$ and $[(T^2 - T + 1)q(T)]$, where $p(T)$ is some polynomial that doesn't divide $(T^2 - T + 1)$, and $q(T)$ is any polynomial that doesn't divide $(T^2 + T + 1)$...

Comment: I understand that $(T^2+T+1)p(T)(T^2-T+1)q(T)=(T^4+T^2+1)p(T)q(T)$, which is divisible by $T^4+T^2+1$ whatever $p(T)$ and $q(T)$ be. So why do you say $p(T)$ should not divide $T^2-T+1$?

Comment: If $p(T)$ divides $T^2-T+1$, then $[(T^2+T+1)p(T)]$ is _itself_ equal to $[0]$; therefore, it doesn't qualify as a zero divisor.

Comment: Yes, that's right! Then the answer to the exercise is: $\left \{ {(T^2+T+1)p(T), p(T) \in Q[T] , p(T)\nmid T^2-T+1)} \right \}$ and $\left \{ {(T^2-T+1)q(T), q(T) \in Q[T] , q(T)\nmid T^2+T+1)} \right \}$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes! I think that's it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Kenny. I'm going to use this forum more often from now :)